# nmake doesn't find any of the WindowsKit files

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, libcurl, nmake

I am currently trying to install a static library of curl. I am basically running this command with VS Command Line :

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static
```

This command is supposed to build the curl binary source that I've downloaded.

But it returns this error:

> *basicpath..*\curl-master\lib\config-win32.h(723): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'ws2tcpip.h' : No such file or directory

It appears that all those files exist and are there (all Windows Kit SDK):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0

I don't understand why it doesn't find those files (I added myself the Windows Kit SDK to PATH). This must be easy; I am annoyed that I can't figure it out myself right now.

Thanks for your help, ask if you need any precision to understand my problem.